# extract substring between multiple words in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame where I need to extract sub-string from each row of a column based on the following conditions

- We have `start_list` (`'one','once I','he'`) and `end_list` (`'fine','one','well'`).
- The sub-string should be preceded by any of the elements of the `start_list`.
- The sub-string may be succeeded by any of the elements of the `end_list`.
- When any of the elements of the `start_list` is available then the succeeding sub string should be extracted with/without the presence of the elements of the `end_list`.

**Example Problem:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['one was fine today', 'we had to drive', ' ','I 
                     think once I was fine eating ham ', 'he studies really 
                     well 
                     and is polite ', 'one had to live well and prosper', 
                     '43948785943one by onej89044809', '827364hjdfvbfv', 
                     '&^%$&*+++===========one kfnv dkfjn uuoiu fine', 'they 
                     is one who makes me crazy'], 
                  'b' : ['11', '22', '33', '44', '55', '66', '77', '', '88', 
                     '99']})
```

**Expected Result:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['was', '','','was ','studies really','had to live',
                       'by','','kfnv dkfjn uuoiu','who makes me crazy'],
                   'b' : ['11', '22', '33', '44', '55', '66', '77', '', 
                       '88','99']})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you. This solution requires *Pandas* of course and also the built-in library *functools*.

**Function: remove_preceders**

This function takes as input a collection of words `start_list` and *str* `string`. It looks to see if any of the items in `start_list` are in `string`, and if so returns only the piece of `string` that occurs after said items. Otherwise, it returns the original `string`.

```
def remove_preceders(start_list, string):
    for word in start_list:
        if word in string:
            string = string[string.find(word) + len(word):]
    return string
```

**Function: remove_succeders**

This function is very similar to the first, except it returns only the piece of `string` that occurs before the items in `end_list`.

```
def remove_succeeders(end_list, string):
    for word in end_list:
        if word in string:
            string = string[:string.find(word)]
    return string
```

**Function: to_apply**

How do you actually run the above functions? The *apply* method allows you to run complex functions on a *DataFrame* or *Series*, but it will then look for as input either a full row or single value, respectively (based on whether you're running on a DF or S).

This function takes as input a function to run & a collection of words to check, and we can use it to run the above two functions:

```
def to_apply(func, words_to_check):
    return functools.partial(func, words_to_check)
```

**How to Run**

```
df['no_preceders'] = df.a.apply(
                         to_apply(remove_preceders, 
                                 ('one', 'once I', 'he'))
                               )
df['no_succeders'] = df.a.apply(
                          to_apply(remove_succeeders, 
                                  ('fine', 'one', 'well'))
                               )
df['substring'] = df.no_preceders.apply(
                          to_apply(remove_succeeders, 
                                  ('fine', 'one', 'well'))
                               )
```

And then there's one final step to remove the items from the `substring` column that were not affected by the filtering:

```
def final_cleanup(row):
    if len(row['a']) == len(row['substring']):
        return ''
    else:
        return row['substring']

df['substring'] = df.apply(final_cleanup, axis=1)
```

**Results**

[image]

Hope this works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the assistance.

Comment: The piece of code works perfectly fine Thanks a ton for the assistance in a short notice

Comment: Awesome! no problem, and glad to hear. Would be great if you can accept the answer then.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Stack-overflow and hence was not aware of the 'accept' button. I was trying to give an 'upvote' but the system was prompting me a response stating that I don't have the minimum reputations. Sorry and thank you very much.

Comment: No problem!! Thank you very much.